# how to clear the character in edittext after enter is pressed

Tags: android

I am using the following code to clear edit text after enter is pressed, but its not working.

```
inText.setOnKeyListener(this);
@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
            inText.setText("");
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Is your statement returning true?

Comment: enter in touch screen

Comment: By not working, do you mean it's not responding at all or is it doing something that isn't what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the onKey method is actually called and what key codes are delivered to it. It is possible that a different event than KEYCODE_ENTER is generated, depending on the input type of you EditText. You could also try using OnEditorActionListener instead of OnKeyListener.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
inText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                inText.setText("");
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE is for the enter